# Error in implementation of AdvancedFilter method

Tags: excel, vba

I'm currently having a hard time using AdvancedFilter in a macro I wrote. Right now I have the following code:

```
Sheets("Run Macro").Activate
Sheets("EO").Range("EORange").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
    CopyToRange:=Sheets("Run Macro").Cells(1, 30), unique:=True
```

I have tried changing the activated sheet from "Run Macro" to "EO", and have had the same results both ways. I'm unfamiliar with the AdvancedFilter method and can't figure out what the issue is with this code, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What's the error? Is that line break actually in your code?

Comment: Does the `EORange` named range include column headers? I can repro an error 1004 complaining about missing or invalid field names if I use a range that doesn't include the column headers.

Comment: Thanks for your comments Mathieu, I edited my post to correct for that line break (in my actual code it is just written as one line). The range "EORange" does include a column header, I ran into that issue a while ago but have since accounted for it. And the error is: Run-time error 1004: Application-defined or object-defined error

Comment: Try executing that line from the immediate pane (Ctrl+G) - you may get a more meaningful error message. Otherwise, we'll need more information about what `EORange` actually is / looks like, because at face value there's nothing wrong with the code itself. Are `Run Macro` and `EO` sheets in the same workbook?

Comment: Mathieu, yes they are in the same workbook. I tried running from the immediate pane and got the same error, but I think I have found the problem. I have two variables `EOLR` and `EONTC` which have the correct value, and then I set `EORange=Range(Cells(1,EONTC),Cells(EOLR,EONTC))`. In trying to find the problem I created two more variables, called `FirstCell=Cells(1,EONTC)` and `SecondCell=Cells(EOLR,EONTC)`. These two variables are actually being stored as strings, they store the contents of the cell they refer to instead of the cell as a range. Any ideas on how to correct this? Thanks so much

Comment: That would be `Set FirstCell = ...` and `Set SecondCell = ...` -- otherwise you are let-coercing the objects and implicitly invoking their *default member*, which in the case of a `Range` objects, yields the cell's value (for a single-cell range) or a 2D variant array containing the cells' values (for a multiple-cell range).